# Difference between OData v3 and OData v4

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, odata

We have a requirement of using both Odata v3 and Odata v4.

Actually we need to hit the web services exposing both these versions. We are using Java platform. What are the changes between these two versions — Will it be a major change?

Query formation to hit those web services changes depending upon the version?
Does the API also change?
What are the technical points we need to take care of while calling both of these versions?

Will there be any difference in the response we get?
I heard the default response for v4 is JSON and for V3 is XML — is that true?

I tried with the below examples:

http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers

http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers

**Kindly provide us the details.**

Answer (score 6):

There are quite some differences between OData v3 and v4, so it is most likely not going to be straightforward to support v4.

- See the [OData v4 Specifications](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-4-0/)
- See [What’s New in OData Version 4.0](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/new-in-odata/v4.0/cn01/new-in-odata-v4.0-cn01.html)

As far as I know the default format in v4 is indeed JSON, but it also supports XML; you're not required to use JSON.

Comment: Tks a lot jesper for ur inputs...............                                                                                              One more question like....is there any changes in forming the query to hit the webservices???http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People('russellwhyte')/Trips?$filter=month(StartsAt) eq 2 and day(StartsAt) eq 1 and year(startsAt) eq 2014

Comment: Tks a lot jesper for ur inputs...............                                                                                              One more question like....is there any changes in forming the query to hit the webservices???                                    http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People('russellwhyte')/Trips?$filter=month(StartsAt) eq 2 and day(StartsAt) eq 1 and year(startsAt) eq 2014.............this is for ODATA v4.....what will be change in the query for ODATAv3.....kindly help me on this...i am totally new to this.

Comment: A while ago I worked on an OData v4 project in Java, but I don't know a lot of details on OData v3. As you can see in the documentation above there are a number of differences, but you'll have to read the specs and do some investigation into the differences that are relevant for your use case. The only thing I can say it that it's not 100% compatible.